# Creat field in access for long text in vb6

Tags: vb.net

How to create the field for 1000 word

```
Set fd = tb.CreateField(Me.Date1.Text, dbText, 1000)
```

I tried this, but not working

Comment: This is not VB.Net. Are you refering to VBScript?

Comment: dbText fields are limited to 255 characters, use `dbMemo` instead.